# Is $\mathcal{A}\vee \mathcal{B}=\{A\cup B : A\in \mathcal{A}, B\in \mathcal{B}\}$ a $\sigma$-Algebra?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be $\sigma$ algebras over $\Omega$. I know that $\mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra, but what about $\mathcal{A}\vee \mathcal{B}=\{A\cup B : A\in \mathcal{A}, B\in \mathcal{B}\}$? It surely contains $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$. Let $C\in \mathcal{A}\vee \mathcal{B}$, i. e. we have $C=A\cup B$ and $\Omega\setminus C=\Omega\setminus (A\cup B)=A^C\cap B^C$, why is this in $\mathcal{A}\vee \mathcal{B}$ and what about the sigma additivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Take, for example, $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(C_1)$ and $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(C_2)$, where $C_1\subset C_2\subset \Omega$. Then
$$
\mathcal{C}=\{A\cup B:A\in \mathcal{A},B\in\mathcal{B}\}=\{\emptyset,C_1,C_2,C_1^c,C_2^c,C_1\cup C_2^c,\Omega\}.
$$
However, $C_2\cap C_1^c\notin \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: What does the notation $\sigma(C)$ mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think it means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_an_arbitrary_family), it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$, i.e., $\{\emptyset, C, C^c, \Omega\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$\begin{align*}
\Omega&=\{1,2,3\},\\
\mathcal{A}&=\{\varnothing,\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2,3\}\},\\
\mathcal{B}&=\{\varnothing,\{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}.
\end{align*}$$

Then
$$\{A\cup B\mid A\in\mathcal{A},B\in\mathcal{B}\} = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\{3\},\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$
which is not closed under complements, since $\{1,3\}\in\mathcal{A}\vee\mathcal{B}$, but the complement, $\{2\}$ is not.